# Visual Studio Team Services Build FTP Upload Error

Tags: ftp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an Angular application that I'm using VSTS to continuously deploy. The problem is that when I check the "Preserve file paths" option in the Advanced section of the FTP Upload step, I get the following error "Unable to create remote directory: / due to error: Error: Syntax error in parameters or arguments." If I uncheck "Preserve file paths", the step runs without error. The files are uploaded to the root directory just without any folder structure. I have "Remote directory" set to "/".

FTP Log

```
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3143303Z ##[section]Starting: FTP Upload: dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3146572Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3146703Z Task         : FTP Upload
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3146804Z Description  : FTP Upload
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3146929Z Version      : 1.128.0
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3147035Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3147182Z Help         : Upload files to a remote machine using the File Transfer Protocol (FTP), or securely with FTPS.  [More Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=809084).
2018-03-09T19:15:50.3147375Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5405453Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=D:\a
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5433886Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5442724Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5453315Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5454681Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5456230Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLEAN
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5458201Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLEANCONTENTS
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5460556Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CREDSTYPE
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5461895Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FILEPATTERNS
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5462991Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_OVERWRITE
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5464593Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PASSWORD
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5465181Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PRESERVEPATHS
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5467054Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOTEPATH
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5469178Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ROOTFOLDER
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5470250Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SERVERURL
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5471593Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TRUSTSSL
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5473030Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_USERNAME
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5475915Z ##[debug]loaded 15
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5900036Z ##[debug]check path : D:\a\_tasks\FtpUpload_6f8c69a5-b023-428e-a125-fccf4efcb929\1.128.0\task.json
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5904137Z ##[debug]set resource file to: D:\a\_tasks\FtpUpload_6f8c69a5-b023-428e-a125-fccf4efcb929\1.128.0\task.json
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5904503Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5927958Z ##[debug]credsType=inputs
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5931350Z ##[debug]credsType=inputs
2018-03-09T19:15:50.5932838Z ##[debug]serverUrl=**********
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6423877Z ##[debug]username=*******
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6424279Z ##[debug]password=*******
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6424486Z ##[debug]rootFolder=D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6424689Z ##[debug]filePatterns=**
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6424889Z ##[debug]remotePath=\
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6425086Z ##[debug]clean=false
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6425562Z ##[debug]cleanContents=false
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6425764Z ##[debug]overwrite=true
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6427302Z ##[debug]preservePaths=true
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6428647Z ##[debug]trustSSL=false
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6433816Z ##[debug]Searching for files to upload
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6437442Z ##[debug]find findPath=D:\a\1\s\dist, options=undefined
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6448064Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6449295Z ##[debug]    is a directory
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6456683Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6457050Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6457333Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\3rdpartylicenses.txt
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6458297Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6458605Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\assets
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6459440Z ##[debug]    is a directory
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6462139Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6463091Z ##[debug]    is a directory
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6463391Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts\MASTOD__.ttf
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6464026Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6464357Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6464622Z ##[debug]    is a directory
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6465358Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\horse_chasing_tail.gif
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6465582Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6468019Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\Yawning_horse.jpg
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6468278Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6469393Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\favicon.ico
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6469992Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6470357Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\index.html
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6470493Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6470652Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6471193Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6471369Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6471530Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6471679Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6472451Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6472599Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\dist\styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6473154Z ##[debug]    is a file
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6473332Z ##[debug]15 results
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6482875Z ##[debug]searching for files using: 1 filePatterns: **
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6483815Z ##[debug]win: Win
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6484105Z ##[debug]Candidates found for match: 15
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6484733Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6486022Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6486828Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\3rdpartylicenses.txt
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6487106Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6487816Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6488210Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts\MASTOD__.ttf
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6488501Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6489321Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\horse_chasing_tail.gif
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6489592Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\Yawning_horse.jpg
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6491507Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\favicon.ico
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6491670Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\index.html
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6491836Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6491987Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6492939Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6494252Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6494547Z ##[debug]searching for files, pattern: D:\a\1\s\dist\**
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6494720Z ##[debug]match patterns: D:\a\1\s\dist\**
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6495418Z ##[debug]match options: [object Object]
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6497148Z ##[debug]applying pattern: D:\a\1\s\dist\**
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6533640Z ##[debug]matched 14 items
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6535574Z ##[debug]Found total matches: 14
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6539444Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6539661Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6540596Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\3rdpartylicenses.txt
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6540872Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6542092Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6543311Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6543478Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts\MASTOD__.ttf
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6543651Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6544536Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6544929Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\horse_chasing_tail.gif
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6545161Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6545411Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\Yawning_horse.jpg
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6545618Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6545856Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\favicon.ico
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6546053Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6546460Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\index.html
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6547110Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6547444Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6547722Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6548107Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6548401Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6548791Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6549099Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6549477Z ##[debug]adding file:   D:\a\1\s\dist\styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6549758Z ##[debug]adding folder: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6565537Z ##[debug]number of files to upload: 15
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6566161Z ##[debug]files to upload: ["D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\3rdpartylicenses.txt","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\assets","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\assets\\fonts","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\assets\\fonts\\MASTOD__.ttf","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\assets\\images","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\assets\\images\\Yawning_horse.jpg","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\assets\\images\\horse_chasing_tail.gif","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\favicon.ico","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\index.html","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js","D:\\a\\1\\s\\dist\\styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css"]
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6567580Z ##[debug]secure ftp=false
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6567893Z ##[debug]port not specifided, using default: 21
2018-03-09T19:15:50.6604879Z connecting to: ftp.site4now.net:21
2018-03-09T19:15:50.9158405Z ##[debug][connection] < '220 Serv-U FTP Server v14.0 ready...\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:50.9162775Z ##[debug][parser] < '220 Serv-U FTP Server v14.0 ready...\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:50.9163969Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=220, buffer='Serv-U FTP Server v14.0 ready...'
2018-03-09T19:15:50.9168281Z ##[debug]ftp client greeting
2018-03-09T19:15:50.9168563Z connected: Serv-U FTP Server v14.0 ready...
2018-03-09T19:15:50.9171052Z ##[debug][connection] > 'USER horser'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.3074212Z ##[debug][connection] < '331 User name okay, need password.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.3074625Z ##[debug][parser] < '331 User name okay, need password.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.3081806Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=331, buffer='User name okay, need password.'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.3090492Z ##[debug][connection] > 'PASS 19Dudley91!!'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.5104040Z ##[debug][connection] < '230 User logged in, proceed.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.5104457Z ##[debug][parser] < '230 User logged in, proceed.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.5148499Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=230, buffer='User logged in, proceed.'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.5148916Z ##[debug][connection] > 'FEAT'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.6672205Z ##[debug][connection] < '211-Extensions supported\r\n UTF8\r\n OPTS MODE;MLST;UTF8\r\n CLNT\r\n CSID Name; Version;\r\n HOST domain\r\n SITE PSWD;SET;ZONE;CHMOD;MSG;EXEC;HELP\r\n AUTH TLS;SSL;TLS-C;TLS-P;\r\n PBSZ\r\n PROT\r\n CCC\r\n SSCN\r\n RMDA directoryname\r\n DSIZ\r\n AVBL\r\n EPRT\r\n EPSV\r\n MODE Z\r\n THMB BMP|JPEG|GIF|TIFF|PNG max_width max_height pathname\r\n REST STREAM\r\n SIZE\r\n MDTM\r\n MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[+-TZ];filename\r\n MFMT\r\n MFCT\r\n MFF Create;Modify;\r\n XCRC filename;start;end\r\n XMD5 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA1 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA256 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA512 filename;start;end\r\n COMB target;source_list\r\n MLST Type*;Size*;Create;Modify*;Perm;Win32.ea;Win32.dt;Win32.dl\r\n211 End (for details use "HELP commmand" where command is the command of interest)\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.6673106Z ##[debug][parser] < '211-Extensions supported\r\n UTF8\r\n OPTS MODE;MLST;UTF8\r\n CLNT\r\n CSID Name; Version;\r\n HOST domain\r\n SITE PSWD;SET;ZONE;CHMOD;MSG;EXEC;HELP\r\n AUTH TLS;SSL;TLS-C;TLS-P;\r\n PBSZ\r\n PROT\r\n CCC\r\n SSCN\r\n RMDA directoryname\r\n DSIZ\r\n AVBL\r\n EPRT\r\n EPSV\r\n MODE Z\r\n THMB BMP|JPEG|GIF|TIFF|PNG max_width max_height pathname\r\n REST STREAM\r\n SIZE\r\n MDTM\r\n MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[+-TZ];filename\r\n MFMT\r\n MFCT\r\n MFF Create;Modify;\r\n XCRC filename;start;end\r\n XMD5 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA1 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA256 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA512 filename;start;end\r\n COMB target;source_list\r\n MLST Type*;Size*;Create;Modify*;Perm;Win32.ea;Win32.dt;Win32.dl\r\n211 End (for details use "HELP commmand" where command is the command of interest)\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.6673867Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=211, buffer='Extensions supported\r\n UTF8\r\n OPTS MODE;MLST;UTF8\r\n CLNT\r\n CSID Name; Version;\r\n HOST domain\r\n SITE PSWD;SET;ZONE;CHMOD;MSG;EXEC;HELP\r\n AUTH TLS;SSL;TLS-C;TLS-P;\r\n PBSZ\r\n PROT\r\n CCC\r\n SSCN\r\n RMDA directoryname\r\n DSIZ\r\n AVBL\r\n EPRT\r\n EPSV\r\n MODE Z\r\n THMB BMP|JPEG|GIF|TIFF|PNG max_width max_height pathname\r\n REST STREAM\r\n SIZE\r\n MDTM\r\n MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[+-TZ];filename\r\n MFMT\r\n MFCT\r\n MFF Create;Modify;\r\n XCRC filename;start;end\r\n XMD5 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA1 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA256 filename;start;end\r\n XSHA512 filename;start;end\r\n COMB target;source_list\r\n MLST Type*;Size*;Create;Modify*;Perm;Win32.ea;Win32.dt;Win32.dl\r\nEnd (for details use "HELP commmand" where command is the command of interest)'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.6675012Z ##[debug][connection] > 'TYPE I'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7393884Z ##[debug][connection] < '200 Type set to I.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7394935Z ##[debug][parser] < '200 Type set to I.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7395185Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=200, buffer='Type set to I.'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7405484Z ##[debug]ftp client ready
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7405934Z uploading files to remote directory: \
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7408246Z ##[debug]uploading files
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7412830Z ##[debug]creating remote directory: \
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7421303Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7421828Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7423594Z ##[debug]creating remote directory: /
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7424259Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7424480Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7425725Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js remote: /0.a271095077847919f949.chunk.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7429444Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\3rdpartylicenses.txt
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7430055Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /3rdpartylicenses.txt
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7430290Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\3rdpartylicenses.txt remote: /3rdpartylicenses.txt
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7430529Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7430714Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /assets
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7431738Z ##[debug]creating remote directory: /assets
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7432669Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7433215Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /assets/fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7433430Z ##[debug]creating remote directory: /assets/fonts
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7433619Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts\MASTOD__.ttf
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7433863Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /assets/fonts/MASTOD__.ttf
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7434065Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\fonts\MASTOD__.ttf remote: /assets/fonts/MASTOD__.ttf
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7434380Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7434614Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /assets/images
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7434830Z ##[debug]creating remote directory: /assets/images
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7435064Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\Yawning_horse.jpg
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7435271Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /assets/images/Yawning_horse.jpg
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7435475Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\Yawning_horse.jpg remote: /assets/images/Yawning_horse.jpg
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7435694Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\horse_chasing_tail.gif
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7435895Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /assets/images/horse_chasing_tail.gif
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7436134Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\assets\images\horse_chasing_tail.gif remote: /assets/images/horse_chasing_tail.gif
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7436344Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\favicon.ico
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7436522Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /favicon.ico
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7436764Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\favicon.ico remote: /favicon.ico
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7436957Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\index.html
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7437159Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /index.html
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7437373Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\index.html remote: /index.html
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7437584Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7437792Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7438030Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js remote: /inline.29d7a9534cdf90ff9fc9.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7438260Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7438483Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7438725Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js remote: /main.8d76a8cead0b0a709f14.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7438954Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7439179Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7439721Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js remote: /polyfills.367619bafcf2473263d3.bundle.js
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7440011Z ##[debug]file: D:\a\1\s\dist\styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7440219Z ##[debug]remoteFile: /styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7440450Z ##[debug]uploading file: D:\a\1\s\dist\styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css remote: /styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css
2018-03-09T19:15:51.7468114Z ##[debug][connection] > 'PWD'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.8218617Z ##[debug][connection] < '257 "/" is current directory.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.8219120Z ##[debug][parser] < '257 "/" is current directory.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.8219407Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=257, buffer='"/" is current directory.'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.8223415Z ##[debug][connection] > 'CWD \\'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.9520666Z ##[debug][connection] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.9521187Z ##[debug][parser] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.9521357Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=250, buffer='Directory changed to /'
2018-03-09T19:15:51.9521494Z ##[debug][connection] > 'CWD /'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.0393165Z ##[debug][connection] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.0393606Z ##[debug][parser] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.0393880Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=250, buffer='Directory changed to /'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.0394108Z ##[debug][connection] > 'PWD'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.0396767Z files uploaded: 0, files skipped: 0, directories processed: 1, total: 1, remaining: 15, remote directory successfully created/verified: \
2018-03-09T19:15:52.1464749Z ##[debug][connection] < '257 "/" is current directory.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.1465971Z ##[debug][parser] < '257 "/" is current directory.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.1466337Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=257, buffer='"/" is current directory.'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.1466773Z ##[debug][connection] > 'CWD /'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.2544396Z ##[debug][connection] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.2544813Z ##[debug][parser] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.2545240Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=250, buffer='Directory changed to /'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.2545470Z ##[debug][connection] > 'CWD '
2018-03-09T19:15:52.3285531Z ##[debug][connection] < '501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.3286288Z ##[debug][parser] < '501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments.\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.3286546Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=501, buffer='Syntax error in parameters or arguments.'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.3287602Z ##[debug][connection] > 'CWD /'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4042501Z ##[debug][connection] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4043030Z ##[debug][parser] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4043359Z ##[debug][parser] Response: code=250, buffer='Directory changed to /'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4048939Z ##[debug][connection] > 'PASV'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4061686Z FTP upload failed: "Unable to create remote directory: / due to error: Error: Syntax error in parameters or arguments.". FTP log: "[connection] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n',[parser] < '250 Directory changed to /\r\n',[parser] Response: code=250, buffer='Directory changed to /',[connection] > 'PASV'".
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4062912Z host: ftp.site4now.net
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4063176Z path: \
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4063359Z files uploaded: 0
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4063550Z files skipped: 0
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4063728Z directories processed: 1
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4063908Z unprocessed files & directories: 15
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4064305Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4120192Z ##[error]Unable to create remote directory: / due to error: Error: Syntax error in parameters or arguments.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4134628Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Unable to create remote directory: / due to error: Error: Syntax error in parameters or arguments.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4148033Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unable to create remote directory: / due to error: Error: Syntax error in parameters or arguments.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4148151Z disconnecting from: ftp.site4now.net
2018-03-09T19:15:52.4900984Z ##[debug][connection] < '227 Entering Passive Mode (208,118,63,179,156,74)\r\n'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6721119Z ##[debug]ftp client end
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6722738Z disconnected
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6723174Z ##[debug]ftp client close, hadErr:false
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6785246Z ##[section]Finishing: FTP Upload: dist
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6794608Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Post Job Cleanup'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6794902Z ##[debug]Always run post-job step: 'Post Job Cleanup'
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6795289Z ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6870577Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: Horse Liberator Website (Git)
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6871062Z ##[debug]Repository url=https://invisiblefury.visualstudio.com/_git/Horse Liberator Website
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6871183Z ##[debug]targetPath=D:\a\1\s
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6871276Z ##[debug]Remove any extraheader, proxy and client cert setting from git config.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6898713Z ##[debug]Remove injected credential from git remote fetch url.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6927337Z ##[debug]Set git fetch url to: https://invisiblefury.visualstudio.com/_git/Horse%20Liberator%20Website for remote: origin.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.6927610Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://invisiblefury.visualstudio.com/_git/Horse%20Liberator%20Website
2018-03-09T19:15:52.7245453Z ##[debug]Remove injected credential from git remote push url.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.7271374Z ##[debug]Set git push url to: https://invisiblefury.visualstudio.com/_git/Horse%20Liberator%20Website for remote: origin.
2018-03-09T19:15:52.7271555Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://invisiblefury.visualstudio.com/_git/Horse%20Liberator%20Website
2018-03-09T19:15:52.7590347Z ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
2018-03-09T19:15:53.2105864Z ##[section]Finishing: Job
```

Comment: For the FTP upload task, setting Remote directory option as `/`, no matter select Preserve file paths options or not, it should upload to FTP successful. Can you show the detail log for FTP upload task by setting `syetem.debug` release variable as `true`? And please also check the physics path for the FTP server is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have uploaded the FTP Logs. I can confirm that the ftp location and username work. I am able to connect via windows explorer, upload, and delete files/folders.

Comment: Based on the log, you use "\"  (not `/`) for Remote directory. What if you change the Remote directory as `/` and build again?

Comment: I have tried it both ways. Both fail.

Comment: What if you manually add the dist folder and it's files to the FTP server root directory (to check if it's allowed to create folder in the root of the FTP server)?

Comment: I am able to manually add to the FTP server.

Comment: What if queue the build with private agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I now believe this is an issue with my hosting company.